# Issues regarding Multiplication of Matrices and Lists in R

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication

I developed a predictive Model by performing  pooled regressions each year and thus I have varying model-coefficients. I stored the different coefficients in a list with lapply(myregressions, coef)  and I would like to use the model-coefficients to make predicitions on a subsample (SS).

I thus have a DF with the subjects (SS) I d like to make predictions, and a “List” with the different model-coefficients for each year:

```
SS

  id time      inc       ta    div      acc   dd     neg
9   1 1995  10.3995 234.4126 2.5155   3.6462 2.5155   0
10  1 1996  10.6098 245.7136 2.7936  -3.8121 2.7936   0
11  1 1997   9.9005 271.3418 2.6359  13.7573 2.6359   0
12  1 1998   8.4780 231.6341 2.6580 -19.0560 2.6580   0
13  1 1999  14.2969 293.2106 2.6992  11.7852 2.6992   0
14  1 2000 159.1115 374.4408 2.7745 223.5071 2.7745   0
15  1 2001 -10.2167 315.3258 4.2379   5.8569 4.2379   1
16  1 2002 -10.8737 207.4538 3.2023 -36.4547 3.2023   1
17  1 2003  10.7719 195.9657 3.0622 -12.2817 3.0622   0
18  1 2004   4.6669 269.0332 3.7677  -6.0882 3.7677   0
19  1 2005   5.5542 235.2783 3.9230 -10.7087 3.9230   0
20  1 2006   5.2375 300.8294 3.8623 -18.7482 3.8623   0
21  1 2007  15.1524 305.0057 3.8131  -9.9801 3.8131   0
22  1 2008  20.8307 307.4744 4.3381 -25.4373 4.3381   0
23  1 2009  33.5010 329.3090 5.2710 -16.7450 5.2710   0
24  1 2010   4.5180 344.7620 5.5650 -15.9290 5.5650   0
25  1 2011   5.7310 330.4060 6.1180  -3.2060 6.1180   0
26  1 2012   9.4360 505.8150 2.8510 -14.9710 2.8510   0
73  3 2007   5.4877 240.1564 1.8500  29.3132 1.8500   0
74  3 2008  14.9182 222.5949 0.0000 -76.0916 0.0000   0
```

and the following Model-Coefficients:

```
> COEF
            Year_1995    Year_1996    Year_1997    Year_1998    Year_1999    Year_2000    Year_2001    Year_2002    Year_2003    Year_2004   Year_2005
(Intercept) -1.416094e+02 -82.29723152 -34.48711235  -6.75285267  39.78186661  51.89597510  23.17918777   6.86072515   5.23465497  -5.08239969  -7.6220984
inc          1.117437e-03  -0.02122991  -0.02947603  -0.05828917  -0.16953822  -0.17572781   0.04419688   0.35492978   0.16529339   0.38122280   0.7805206
ta           9.491843e-02   0.07728032   0.08736790   0.07941649   0.05278938   0.04884008   0.04428136   0.02858724   0.02813507   0.01588882   0.0168884
div         -2.110746e+00  -0.41682760  -0.28204986   0.63646277   2.40335454   2.47957711   1.75339550   1.15411677   1.85791345   1.43288590   0.2259217
acc         -2.925896e-01  -0.08831186   0.06483823   0.15384923   0.15693459   0.08828990  -0.04028631  -0.04648089   0.03157282  -0.23257706  -0.2823107
dd           8.246035e+01  30.23337379 -23.72154753 -47.38041382 -84.13134965 -95.56086167 -58.06399289 -21.61298500 -12.11352064 -15.77302514 -26.3842782
neg         -1.381479e+02  25.15047622  31.05613176  60.76519163  56.06664314 -36.13696534 -27.42185598 -24.58473166 -38.36806501 -25.03186619  17.3447807
           Year_2006    Year_2007    Year_2008    Year_2009     Year_2010   Year_2011
(Intercept) -17.46962445 -12.99847554 -32.75957413 -20.99868791 -16.816973260  4.20348639
inc           0.92593004   0.77045742   0.78774688   0.85185356   0.784377210  0.63716695
ta            0.01374169   0.02841329   0.02729613   0.01045620   0.005867683 -0.00203465
div          -0.29770950  -0.20114307  -0.18070822   0.04780002   0.310500463  0.69699053
acc          -0.23553147  -0.18337198  -0.11535837  -0.12223995  -0.083179505 -0.08493535
dd           12.00464005 -15.31475612  18.57613650   8.13129910   8.855194809  0.86265216
neg          13.84589134  -6.42677325  24.44777629  39.13989889  31.941025536  5.76845025
```

I'm quite lost on how to do this by code however.

I tried to set the time variable as a factor (level) and then somehow link it to the correct model (year), but i didn't get it to work. Here is what i came up so far:

```
as.factor(SS$time)
for (f in levels(SS$time)) {
SS$Forecast<-NA
  SS[which(set$time == f),]$Forecast <- c(SS[which(SS$time == f),]$SS[,cbind("inc","ta","div","acc","dd","neg"] %*% COEF$Year_(f)[-1,])
```

I don't know how to correctly address the columns with the correct year for the model.

To further specify: Here is the model i'm using:

```
## Store each subset regression in myregression(list)
myregression <- list()
count <- 1
## pooled regression in each year t, over the previous 6 years:
for(t in 1995:2011){

  myregression[[count]] <- lm(inc.plus1 ~ inc+ta+div+acc+dd+neg, 
                           subset(mydata, time<=t & time>=t-5))
## Name each regression based on the year:
names(myregression)[[count]] = paste0("Year_",t)
count <- count+1
}
```

Edit:

```
dput(COEF)
structure(list(Year_1995 = structure(c(-141.609371159809, 0.00111743731163439, 
0.0949184274697431, -2.11074600795104, -0.292589586724503, 82.4603460821799, 
-138.147911474103), .Names = c("(Intercept)", "inc", "ta", "div", 
"acc", "dd", "neg")), Year_1996 = structure(c(-82.2972315187381, 
-0.0212299058617464, 0.0772803184315252, -0.416827603793079, 
-0.0883118611861919, 30.2333737922913, 25.1504762235072), .Names = c("(Intercept)", 
"inc", "ta", "div", "acc", "dd", "neg")), Year_1997 = structure(c(-34.4871123463234, 
-0.0294760332129564, 0.0873679009872829, -0.282049864938565, 
0.0648382318254867, -23.7215475326697, 31.0561317591284), .Names = c("(Intercept)", 
"inc", "ta", "div", "acc", "dd", "neg")), Year_1998 = structure(c(-6.7528526732182, 
-0.0582891693780869, 0.0794164909970893, 0.636462774078724, 0.153849232685583, 
-47.3804138199355, 60.7651916263095), .Names = c("(Intercept)", 
"inc", "ta", "div", "acc", "dd", "neg")), Year_1999 = structure(c(39.7818666097103, 
-0.169538215393184, 0.0527893752400966, 2.40335453967921, 0.156934591577236, 
-84.1313496511335, 56.0666431355059), .Names = c("(Intercept)", 
"inc", "ta", "div", "acc", "dd", "neg")), Year_2000 = structure(c(51.8959751012077, 
-0.175727806845858, 0.0488400845863005, 2.4795771094385, 0.0882899033509166, 
-95.5608616726431, -36.1369653445477), .Names = c("(Intercept)", 
"inc", "ta", "div", "acc", "dd", "neg")), Year_2001 = structure(c(23.1791877732751, 
0.0441968784823003, 0.0442813644637717, 1.75339550336409, -0.0402863054679132, 
-58.063992891827, -27.4218559824398), .Names = c("(Intercept)", 
"inc", "ta", "div", "acc", "dd", "neg")), Year_2002 = structure(c(6.86072514828435, 
0.354929778347401, 0.0285872368436264, 1.15411677489571, -0.046480887062018, 
-21.6129850032949, -24.5847316572374), .Names = c("(Intercept)", 
"inc", "ta", "div", "acc", "dd", "neg")), Year_2003 = structure(c(5.23465497240386, 
0.165293389856035, 0.0281350748183987, 1.85791345171875, 0.0315728168554789, 
-12.1135206433413, -38.3680650149334), .Names = c("(Intercept)", 
"inc", "ta", "div", "acc", "dd", "neg")), Year_2004 = structure(c(-5.08239969344246, 
0.38122280421443, 0.0158888214408302, 1.43288589529407, -0.232577057535449, 
-15.7730251398318, -25.031866190808), .Names = c("(Intercept)", 
"inc", "ta", "div", "acc", "dd", "neg")), Year_2005 = structure(c(-7.62209838055104, 
0.780520600545447, 0.0168883991578571, 0.225921710905689, -0.282310746447424, 
-26.3842781765152, 17.3447807493898), .Names = c("(Intercept)", 
"inc", "ta", "div", "acc", "dd", "neg")), Year_2006 = structure(c(-17.4696244494262, 
0.925930038022017, 0.0137416876286758, -0.297709497723217, -0.235531473622334, 
12.0046400465099, 13.8458913438642), .Names = c("(Intercept)", 
"inc", "ta", "div", "acc", "dd", "neg")), Year_2007 = structure(c(-12.9984755404426, 
0.770457416822948, 0.0284132933700557, -0.201143068996775, -0.183371982389497, 
-15.3147561235654, -6.42677324935822), .Names = c("(Intercept)", 
"inc", "ta", "div", "acc", "dd", "neg")), Year_2008 = structure(c(-32.7595741256977, 
0.787746882558884, 0.0272961331794223, -0.180708217282236, -0.115358369479928, 
18.5761365038557, 24.4477762931961), .Names = c("(Intercept)", 
"inc", "ta", "div", "acc", "dd", "neg")), Year_2009 = structure(c(-20.9986879109346, 
0.851853556341307, 0.0104562009202871, 0.0478000168970218, -0.122239947105099, 
8.13129909792091, 39.1398988903904), .Names = c("(Intercept)", 
"inc", "ta", "div", "acc", "dd", "neg")), Year_2010 = structure(c(-16.8169732598254, 
0.784377210327309, 0.00586768328571868, 0.310500462697048, -0.0831795048437002, 
8.85519480867171, 31.941025535722), .Names = c("(Intercept)", 
"inc", "ta", "div", "acc", "dd", "neg")), Year_2011 = structure(c(4.20348638599851, 
0.637166947185806, -0.00203465043623203, 0.696990528517877, -0.0849353510171298, 
0.862652164443496, 5.76845024650845), .Names = c("(Intercept)", 
"inc", "ta", "div", "acc", "dd", "neg"))), .Names = c("Year_1995", 
"Year_1996", "Year_1997", "Year_1998", "Year_1999", "Year_2000", 
"Year_2001", "Year_2002", "Year_2003", "Year_2004", "Year_2005", 
"Year_2006", "Year_2007", "Year_2008", "Year_2009", "Year_2010", 
"Year_2011"))
```

Comment: It would have been easier if instead of storing the coefficients, you actually stored the model object. Then you could have used the standard `predict()` function. Is there a reason you did not do this?

Comment: I stored the regression as well, I was not aware of the predict function however. I will quickly read about it now. Thank you for the advice

Comment: as the predict function also allows me to use new data, i guess i can also use that function. So i performed the following: PREDICTION<-lapply(myregression, function(x) predict(x, SS)) and get another list. I would get a prediction for every observation irrespective of the year and would have to delete all years that are not the respective "model-year". Which solution is quicker/ more efficient in your opinion?

Comment: It seems to me that the indexing (id, time) info gets lost by using the prediction function (at least in the way I use it).

Comment: I guess it's still unclear to me exactly what you are doing or how you generated your models in the first place. So you want to have different slopes for each variable for each year? It seems like you should have just had one model with an interaction term for year.

Comment: I specified the model in the Edit below. I believe the aim of the model is to allow for a time-variation of the slope parameters.

Comment: Post dput(COEF) since at the moment it is entirely unclear what sort of object it really is, and with R .... THAT DOES MATTER. I don't think this involves matrix multiplication and labeling as "complex" just confuses people who might come here looking for operations on matrices composed of complex numbers.

Comment: I just posted the dput(COEF) output and renamed the topic. thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have different coefficient estimates for each year, there's no reason to fit individual models for each year, you can just add an interaction term for year to all your coefficients. For example, here's a reduced sample dataset

```
set.seed(15)
dd<-data.frame(
    year=factor(sample(2001:2005, 50, replace=T)),
    inc = runif(50),
    tc=runif(50),
    y=rnorm(50)
)
```

Now we can fit a model for all the values in the data set with a year interaction term,

```
m1 <- lm(y~(inc+tc)*year, dd)
```

or we can fit a model for just year 2005

```
m2 <- lm(y~inc+tc, subset(dd, year==2005))
```

then when we go to predict the values for 2005, we see that both

```
predict(m1, subset(dd, year==2005))
predict(m2, subset(dd, year==2005))
```

return the same predictions

```
         3          6          7         10         15 
 1.0488444  0.2317228  1.4672413  0.8638882  0.5296259 
        16         18         21         29         41 
 0.4944689  1.2231755  0.7690225  0.6869038 -0.5844771 
        43         49 
 0.5610021  0.3552466
```

But of course `m1` has the advantage of being able to predict for any year rather than having to fit an `m2` type model for each year.

Comment: TIf i am just doing a simple regression each year, i believe your model and mine would be equivalent (and yours of course being much simpler and convenient). But i am estimating different slopes in year t, based on 6 pooled regressions from year t-5 until t and not just from year t. Please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: thank you again for your answer. I just wanted to let you know that i reformulated the question with the focus on the predict function in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849234/model-prediction-for-pooled-regression-model-in-panel-data I'm hesitating however to delete this question as you already wrote an answer. What do you suggest?